# Would Java be a good option to use as a programming language for ROS?

Tags: c++, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not well versed with C++ so would using RosJava would be a better option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190320/would-java-be-a-good-option-to-use-as-a-programming-language-for-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python would be the preferred language for ROS imho. It's very easy to learn and very powerful as well. Maybe that would be an option?

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on 2014-08-15**:
I agree with @Chrissi. Try python if find C++ difficult. It's very easy and robust programming language!

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-08-18**:
I'd like to add that I find C++ somehow closer to Java than python so since the poster is a Java expert, it might be easier for him to start with C++.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am not well versed with C++ so would using RosJava would be a better option?

While `rosjava` is certainly an option, I would recommend starting with `roscpp` or `rospy` (as the other posters have written). Once you get acquainted with ROS terminology and concepts, `rosjava` will probably start to make more sense. It is far more asynchronous and harder to 'wrap your head around' than any of the other client libraries (although if you are proficient enough in Java that asynchronicity should not really matter).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2